# Generalization of Kneser's graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let's consider subsets of the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ which consist of $m$ elements. I wonder, what is the maximal number of such subsets such that cardinality of intersection of any two of them isn't equal to $k$. Let's call $f(n,m,k)$.

I considered some cases and proved, for instance, the equality $f(4n,3,1)=4n$.

Is there a general way to compute values of $f$?

Comment: If $k=0$, you are looking for the maximum size of an intersecting family, which is known by the Erdos-Ko-Rado theorem.

Comment: @AshwinGanesan Yes, I know, I'm interested in the case $k>0$. For instance, $k=1,2$.

Comment: See: P. Keevash, D. Mubayi, R.M. Wilson [Set systems with no singleton intersections](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/keevash/papers/no-singleton-journal.pdf), where $k=1$ is considered. There are references to prior related results there, and there were some later studies too.